# When opining a PDF with Python tkPDFViewer throws an error, is there an mistake I'm not seeing?

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, tkpdfviewer

When testing the opening of a PDF for a larger project the code throws an error.  The error emanates from the tkPDFViewer.
Any ideas?

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (add_img): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner self.run()
File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run self._target(*self._args, *self._kwargs) 
File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tkPDFViewer\tkPDFViewer.py", line 46, in add_img
pix = page.getPixmap()
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'getPixmap'. Did you mean: 'get_pixmap'?
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

print('Starting TestPDF2')

mainWindow = tk.Tk()
  
# Set the width and height of our root window.
mainWindow.geometry("550x750")
  
# creating object of ShowPdf from tkPDFViewer.
v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
  
# Adding pdf location and width and height.
v2 = v1.pdf_view(mainWindow, pdf_location = 'testpdf.pdf', width = 50, height = 100)
  
# Placing Pdf in my gui.
v2.pack()
mainWindow.mainloop()

print('End TestPDF2')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal problem with tkPDFViewer. The error is quite self-explanatory - `getPixmap` was deprecated and removed in favor of `get_pixmap` in one of the dependencies of tkPDFViewer (see [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/znames.html)). So the library needs to get fixed (the methods need to be renamed to match the new version) and it doesn't look very well maintained. You can try opening an issue or a PR on its GitHub. But I'd probably lean towards saying this library is dead and broken, and finding yourself an alternative that works.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping someone new of an updated PDF library or an alternate.

Answer (score 0):

**Your can fix tkPDFViewer yourself.  Open tkPDFViewer.py, search for these two lines:**

pix = page.getPixmap()

img = pix1.getImageData("ppm")

**and replace them like this:**

pix = page.get_pixmap()

img = pix1.tobytes("ppm")

Save tkPDFViewer.py, then it should work.